# Object Inspoector for JavaScript (preferrably AngularJs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Several IDEs provide an [Object Inspector](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Object_Inspector) for the developer to allow them to examine and set properties of an object (e.g height, width, text of a button).

[image]

I would like to incorporate an Object Inspector into a design program which I am developing. Does anyone know of one?

Preferably gratis, preferably AngularJs, but I will pay for a good solution & can live with plain old JS if I have to.

---

[Update]  My apologies - I did not make my needs clear.

I want to offer such an inspector only for some parts of data which my program decides to make public. So, I could maybe take an existing one and edit it. I guess what I want is an "object inspector builder" - which starts off empty, until I programmatically add data to it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [ng-inspector](http://ng-inspector.org/)? It is a free browser extension that will allow you to inspect the bindings and objects you have in AngularJS right in your browser as your application executes.

Comment: Good siuggestion (+1). BUT, plase see updated question; I did not ask very well